# Tracing the path of a dispatcher.forward

Tags: java, servlets, dispatcher, requestdispatcher

I'm editing code that is not my own, and need to follow the path of a RequestDispatcher.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServlet().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher([url]);

if (dispatcher == null) {
throw new Exception("Unable to find " + [url]);
            }

logger.debug("Dispatching request to PDF Writer Servlet " + dispatcher.toString());

dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

How can I find out where the path will take me?

Comment: You can use a debugger. That might be a little hard to do with `jsp` resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the line dispatcher.forward(request, response) and add this line and then try running the servlet.

out.print(this.getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath([url]));

This shall return the path to which the dispatcher will get forwarded to.